# Perform MySql Fulltext Search using NHibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to execute a statement like this in NHibernate?

```
SELECT * FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE
    field2 = "word" 
OR  
    MATCH (field1) AGAINTS ('wordA' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Either [register the function in the dialect](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.aspx) or use `Expression.Sql`.